# How to iterate over a Groovy Collection in Javascript from GSP view

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I'm trying to iterate over the collection "times" in the code below. It's a list of map objects, each map has a time, name and modified field.

```
<r:script>
    <% def pos = 0%>
    for(var i = 0; i < ${jsonTimes.size()}; i++){
        console.log(${jsonTimes[pos].getAt("time")});
       <% pos++; %>
    }
</r:script>
```

either incrementing the "pos" variable as I am here, or jsonTimes[pos++] fails to increment the variable. Can I get some help with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing groovy and js. `jsonTimes` is a server side variable, so you should use groovy for iterations:

```
<g:each in="${jsontTimes}" var="jt">
  console.log(${jt.getAt("time").encodeAsJavaScript()});
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly it, I had tried this before simplifying to a console.log(), I guess I did something wrong. Thanks again!